# Not able to get value of a Radio element

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I have a button on a page that when a user pushes it, it creates another "radio element" on the page. The problem though is that I am having a hard time retrieving the value with PHP after the form is submitted.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" id="rad-3" title="member-section" name="use_name[0]" value="Test!" />
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
if ($_POST['use_name[0]'] == 'Test!') {
    echo 'It Worked!' ;
} else {
    echo 'Nope!' ;
}
```

Whenever my form is submitted, Nope! is always echoed out. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will receive `$_POST['use_name']` as an array, with the `[0]` key you specified in the HTML. So you want to test:

```
if ($_POST['use_name'][0] == 'Test') {
 // ....
}
```

Debug with `print_r($_POST)` to see the structure of the array.

Note that if you don't have a need to send specific array keys in the HTML, you can just name the inputs like `name='use_name[]'` and PHP will receive them as a numeric-indexed array.  You can be more specific if needed, with string keys too: `name='use_name[first_value]'` and PHP will receive the string keys as in `$_POST['use_name']['first_value']`

Note however, that this is *not* a typical way to use radio buttons.  Since only one is usually selected, unless you are listing multiple radio buttons (we don't see your HTML) all with the name `name='use_name[0]` the buttons will not be bound as a radio group. They must all have the same name, and different array keys will turn them into different radio groups.  This is more commonly used for checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you very much! One last concern. How would I access the value with the HTML name as: member[0][fname]

Comment: Inspect the `$_POST` with `print_r($_POST)`.  It would be `$_POST['member'][0]['fname']`

Answer (score 0):

Your POST variable is an array in php, so you can access it like:

```
$_POST['use_name'][0]
```